# how to get distinct student id whose subjects are only ' maths and science ' from a table student

Tags: mysql

TABLE

```
+------+-----------+
| ID   | subject   |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | science   |
|    1 | maths     |
|    2 | maths     |
|    3 | science   |
|    4 | science   |
|    4 | biology   |
|    4 | maths     |
|    5 | biology   |
|    5 | economics |
+------+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

from above table want a query to get distinct id whose subjects are SCIENCE AND MATHS

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(`ID`)
FROM 
  `TABLE` 
WHERE 
  `subject` IN ('science', 'maths');
```

Updated:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT  ,
  subject varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO test (id, subject) VALUES 
(1,'science'),
(1,'maths'),
(2,'maths'),
(3,'science'),
(4,'science'),
(4,'biology'),
(4,'maths'),
(5,'biology'),
(5,'economics');

SELECT
  DISTINCT(a.id)
FROM 
  test a
  LEFT JOIN test b on b.id=a.id  AND b.subject IN ('science', 'maths')
WHERE 
  a.subject='science' AND b.subject='maths';
/*output: 1, 4*/
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have tried the above query, but the output was also who have just science or just maths...

Comment: Distinct is not a function

Comment: And `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x =` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: @Strawberry Is there any performance difference for: using `DISTINCT()` (with the `(`|`)`) or my current `JOIN`?

Comment: `()` is simply ignored. Without testing, I couldn't say whether the process of ignoring takes time. Likewise, the JOIN is rendered as an inner join, but again I'd need to test to see what impact it would have. Definitely, as written, it does nothing to aid performance.

Comment: Well, technically it's misleading. It's also wrong, but for other reasons, which I won't elaborate on because the thread starter's question simply isn't good enough, but these reasons are touched upon in the other answer provided (except it's wrong too)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select distinct id
from tablename
where subject in ('science', 'maths')
having count(distinct subject)=2
```

Comment: Ahh, I always forget about the `HAVING` clause